# Check calendars from Exchange to know when a person is out of office

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, exchange-server, exchange

Environment: Sharepoint Foundation 2010

I want to check calendars from an Exchange Server. It is to know when a person is out of office.

This will be useful to transfer a workflow task automatically with this/another workflow. Thing is I don't want to manage them into Sharepoint, just read them to work with.

Is it possible to get information from an Exchange Server ?

Answer (score 2):

I am running into almost same issue where i need to show exchange calendar of everyone in SharePoint.

If you just want to show the exchange calendar events timing, then probably the Calendar Overlay in SharePoint is the best approach for you. But it will show the event time and the status i.e **Busy, Free, In Meeting** etc not the actual event detail i.e **Meeting with Boss, Annual Dinner** etc. Only one's own exchange calendar will be visible to him after login into SharePoint. No one else can see other's calendar. Below is the guide to setup Calendar Overlay.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2011/05/31/sharepoint-and-exchange-calendar-together/

The other method is using custom code development. You can write some custom code to query the exchange server with any valid login ID to get Calendar events. You can use impersonation in code and then can query anyone's exchange Calendar. For implementing impersonation, you would need a service account that would have read access on all exchange calendars. Below is a sample web part that fetches emails from exchange by implementing impersonation. You can modify the code according to your requirements.

https://exchangewp.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very interesting! I saw the impersonation. It's a good alternative. But, unfortunately, I don't have an access to the Central Administration Center. I think you don't have another way to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately till now that's not possible using any method specially without jumping into CA. There is one more approach by adding OOTB OWA Webparts in SharePoint but that also requires authentication and Calendar will be visible only to the owner of that Calendar.